# Exception Handling on async tasks whenall

Tags: c#

I am using [Using async/await for multiple tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337671/using-async-await-for-multiple-tasks) as reference.

```
public async Task DoWork() {

    int[] ids = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    await Task.WhenAll(ids.Select(i => DoSomething(1, i, blogClient)));
}
```

Is it possible to catch an exception on the specific index. As in, when DoSomething throws an exception on i, I can catch that specific index?

Comment: If there isn't, you can have your individual DoSomething functions throw an exception with the index as part of the data, then catch it at the DoWork level

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Task WhenAll exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52675789/task-whenall-exception-handling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to catch the Exception, insert the index information on the exception's Data, and rethrow :

```
int[] ids = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
await Task.WhenAll(ids.Select(i =>
{
    try
    {
        return DoSomething(1, i, null);
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.Data["FailedIndex"] = i; // Information about failed index
        throw;
    }
}));
```